# How to display if file path is right? Image or not image

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, image, path

I can't figure out how to get the cmd to display whether the user has input the correct file path for an image. I know I have to console.??? but I'm not sure how to write it out.

Set up:

1. User inputs their file path
2. CMD takes that info and tells them whether it's a image file (0xFFD8 file) or not
3. CMD then creates a .CSV file containing the file path, file type, and MD5 hash

I'm stuck at getting the cmd to tell the user whether it's a jpg file or not.

Any idea where I'm going wrong in my code?

```
internal class Program
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your file path location:");
        string mainFile = MainFileInput();


        Console.WriteLine("Let's determine what type of file this is:");
        string typeFile = ImageType();
    }

    public static string MainFileInput()
    {
        string mainFile = Console.ReadLine();
        while (File.Exists(mainFile) == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main file does not exist. Please enter another file: ");
            mainFile = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("File exists.");
        return mainFile;
    }

    public static ImageType HeaderType(string typefile)
    {
        string checkType;
        byte[] headerBytes;
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(typefile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            const int mostBytesNeeded = 11;//For JPEG

            if (fileStream.Length < mostBytesNeeded)
                return ImageType.Unknown;

            headerBytes = new byte[mostBytesNeeded];
            fileStream.Read(headerBytes, 0, mostBytesNeeded);
        }
        if (headerBytes[0] == 0xFF &&//FF D8)
        {
            return ImageType.JPEG;
        }
        return ImageType.Unknown;
    }
    public enum ImageType
    {
        Unknown,
        JPEG,
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call `HeaderType(...)` from `Main` with your filename, then `Console.WriteLine` the return value you get of type `ImageType` (use `.ToString()`).

Comment: @wohlstad I'm a newbie. So I would write Console.WriteLine("Let's determine what type of file this is:");
        Program.HeaderType(); 
  Console.WriteLine("Your file type is:" ImageType.ToString());

Comment: Added a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method `HeaderType(...)` from `Main` with your file name (`mainFile` - after you received it from calling the method `MainFileInput(...)`).

The return value from `HeaderType(...)` will be of type `ImageType`.
You can print it after converting to string using `.ToString()` method.

So your complete `Main` will be something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your file path location:");
    string mainFile = MainFileInput();

    Console.WriteLine("Let's determine what type of file this is:");
    ImageType theType = HeaderType(mainFile);
    Console.WriteLine("Image type: " + theType.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping a newbie out! Much appreciated.